# image upload and save with multiple copies / names

Tags: php, file-upload, copy, rename

How do I upload an images and then save with a different name and multiple copies in the same directory ?

One copy of the uploaded image(abcd.jpg) needs to be named  '212_1_today_00.jpg' and another copy needs be named '424_1_today_00.jpg' and may be another '848_1_today_01.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I uploaded one with the name '212_1_today_00.jpg' and I copied using PHP function - `copy` 
Found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

```
<?php
$file = './myfolder/212_1_today_00.jpg';
$newfile = './myfolder/424_1_today_00.jpg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

better use time() instead of today as random no might be repeated at some point.......

```
<?php
if($_FILES){
    $image = $_FILES['image'];
    if($image['error'] == 0){
        $a = explode('.',$image['name']);
        $e = end($a);
        $t = time();
        $name = rand(100, 999)."_1_{$t}";
        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $name.'_00.'.$e);

        # if u want 1 copy
        copy($name.'_00.'.$e, rand(100, 999)."_1_{$t}_01.{$e}");

        # if u want n more copies
        /*
        $n = 5; #no of copies u want
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
            copy($name.'_00.'.$e, rand(100, 999)."_1_{$t}_0{$i}.{$e}");
        }
        */
        echo 'Done';

    }
}

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept='image/*'/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```